# keep getting the error code no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am just starting out with SQL and I have been attepmting to see where the issue is with my SQL below. ive etaken out "Date_Reserved" and was allowed to create the table. However I have made sure to create a primary for "Date Reserved" and it still dosent work

```
create table reservation 
 ( Booking_Number    varchar(8)    not null,
   Room_Number       number(1,50)  not null,
   Date_Reserved     date          not null,
   primary key (Booking_Number, Room_Number, Date_Reserved),
   foreign key (Booking_Number) references booking(Booking_Number),
   foreign key (Room_Number)    references room(Room_Number)
);
 
create table additional_extra
  ( Booking_Number    varchar(8)   not null,
    Room_Number       number(1,50) not null,
    Extra_ID          varchar(8)   not null,
    Date_Reserved     date          not null,
    primary key (Booking_Number, Room_Number, Extra_ID),
    foreign key (Booking_Number) references booking(Booking_Number),
    foreign key (Date_Reserved)  references reservation(Date_Reserved),
    foreign key (Room_Number)    references room(Room_Number),
    foreign key (Extra_ID)       references extra(Extra_ID)
);
```

It keeps resulting in the Error code ""

```
Error report -
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

Comment: You **MUST ALWAYS** reference the **WHOLE** primary key in your table - if your table `reservation` defines the PK to be on **three columns**, the FK from table `additional_extra` MUST also use **ALL THREE COLUMNS** to establish the FK relationship. You **CANNOT** reference only part of a PK - it's an all or nothing thing

Comment: Good point, @marc_s . To me, it's also yet another argument for single-column, single-purpose, surrogate primary keys having no other purpose than being unique row-identifiers, like auto-increment int/bigint or maybe uuid/guid types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key for the **additional_extra** table

```
foreign key (Date_Reserved)  references reservation(Date_Reserved)
```

does not reference all of the columns in the **reservation**  table

```
primary key (Booking_Number, Room_Number, Date_Reserved)
```

[Foreign keys](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/data-integrity.html#GUID-7CD73D16-EA1A-4AA8-AA7D-4288557395B8) may be defined as multiple columns. However, a composite foreign key must reference a composite primary or unique key with the same number of columns and the same data types.